# Firebase Security rules comparison logic

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a question about how cloud firestore security rules' logic works:

Lets say I have rule such as this:

`allow read: if (auth.token.user === true && request.query.limit < 100 && uidInDocument()) || auth.token.admin === true && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.name == "foo";`

Now, my question here is if the first part of the or statement is true, does that mean that the second part doesn't execute? I'm thinking about this as I don't want to be incurring reads *unless* it is necessary to do so, in this case if the user is an `admin`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - could I ask why you downvoted my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean expression in security rules evaluate left to right and short circuit just like pretty much all other programming languages.  If you have a series of logical AND operations, and the first one is false, then the entire rule is finished, and access is rejected.

Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Boolean) for more information.